# In the while loop when I answer yes for the first time and then I answer no it do the loop again and don’t break the loop

Tags: python, loops, debugging, while-loop, break

Anybody know why it doing this
When I answer yes for the first time it start over as it should and then i say no for second time but it ask the question again and don’t break the loop but when i say no for third  time it break the loop and close the app

My question is why it don’t break the loop for the second time

```
def hello():
    print("hello")

    while True:
        answer = input("what do u wanna do")
        if answer == "yes":
            hello()
        elif answer == "no":
            input("Press Enter To Close")
            print("bye")
            import time
            time.sleep(1)
            break
        else:
            print("I didn't understand that")
    
hello()
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. After you say `no` it just says `Press enter to close` and if you press enter, then it closes.

Comment: Try the code now u will see

Comment: Your `while` loop should be outside the function `hello()`. Then, it works as you wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `while` loop is inside the iterative function `hello()`, even though you use `break`, your code does not stop at the first call, but at the second.

What the self-iteration does there is that it basically goes back to the stack place it left first. Then, when you entered "no" for the second time, it's ready to function as you wanted.
Because of the very same reason, you'll notice that when you immediately hit "no" instead of "yes" in the beginning, the code stops running indeed.

If you put `while` outside the function, it'd work. The reason so many people made it work at first shot was because when we copied and pasted, the indentation of code comes wrong, hence puts `while` already outside ^^'

Answer (score 0):

When your answer is no you are calling for an input but instead you  just want to print a message.

```
def hello():
print("hello")

while True:
    answer = input("what do u wanna do")
    if answer == "yes":
        hello()
        
elif answer == "no":
    print("Press Enter To Close")
    print("bye")
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    break
else:
    print("I didn't understand that")
```

Comment: Try the code u will see

Comment: @WilliamYarWe It works fine for me.`what do u wanna doyes
hello
what do u wanna dono
Press Enter To Close
bye` This is the output  I am getting for your code

Comment: `elif` and `else` indentation here is faulty, but it normally works fine, yep.

Answer (score 0):

Shortenting the program a bit:

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
    while True:
        answer = input("what do u wanna do")
        if answer == "yes":
            hello()
        elif answer == "no":
            break
        else:
            print("I didn't understand that")

hello()
```

Every time you enter "no", the program leaves (`break`) a `while` loop. Since the program unconditionally enters the outermost `while` loop, you need to enter "no" at least once to end the program.

Every time you enter "yes", function `hello` does not return, but calls itself ("recursion") and enters an additional `while` loop. So for each "yes", you need to enter one additional "no".

To illustrate, here are a few sample interactions.
An opening parenthesis calls `hello`, entering a loop,
A closing parenthesis leaves a loop and returns from a `hello` call.

```
(                                             no ->) end
(yes -> (no ->)                               no ->) end
(yes -> (no ->) yes -> (no ->)                no ->) end
(yes -> (no ->) yes -> (no ->) yes -> (no ->) no ->) end
(yes -> (yes -> (no ->) no ->)                no ->) end
```